# scala - compare tuple or intersect by key of more than 1 tuple

Tags: scala

I have:

a list of (Int, Int) - call that A 
a List of ((Int, Int), (value,value)) - call that B
and I want to replace (Int Int) with (value,value) if the (Int, Int) in A matches the (Int,Int) in B.

Any efficient way of doing this?

EDIT

Currently, I'm using Spark RDD join to do this;

```
val A = List((1,2),(2,3),(3,4))
val B = List(((1,2),("a","b")),((2,3),("c","d")))

val A_rdd = sc.parallelize(A).map(a=>(a,None))
val B_rdd = sc.parallelize(B)

Intersect = A_rdd.join(B_rdd).map(ans=>(ans._1,ans._2._2))
```

EDIT 2

So the full problem is that I have massive List of Different Keys which represent different status in paired numeric INT codes. The list looks something like:

List((Int,Int),(Int,Int),(Int,Int)...) each Row of data represent a session that has a series of paired numeric Int codes.

I have a Key Look Up table in the form of:

List(((Int,Int),(Value,Value)),((Int,Int),(Value,Value)).... )

which represents the translation of the numeric INT pairs. I want to translate each (Int,Int) pair in each Row of data so that the result look something like:

List((Value,Value),(Value,Value),(Value,Value),(Value,Value)...)

I currently have this process running in Spark - and it's tedious because I have to do a RDD join operation each of the INT pair and then mapping the result back to the correct format. So 10 INT pairs would translate to 10 RDD joins between a very big Dataset and a smaller translation Set.

I'm looking for an efficient method to make the translation as a simple Map process. I think what I might do is to zip the INT pair into a single String and do a Map Intersect.

EDIT 3 --

So I've done a pretty crappy solution here, but it works faster than the current method...

```
 def mergeMap (a:(Int,Int)) = {
    val mapa = Map((a,None))
    val merge = mapa.keySet.intersect(translation.keySet).map(k => k->(translation(k))).toMap
    merge
  }
```

so I apply this function to each of the (INT,INT) pair, and so far, it's about 30x faster than all the RDD joins I'm doing

Comment: Edited to add code + current working method

Comment: What do you mean with intersecting the tuples here? Can you show us how the output should look? Also can you show us why it becomes tedious?

Comment: Edited to clarify the problem and explain why my current solution is quite redundant

Comment: If the data is not too big you can do something like this: `val lookUp = Map((Int, Int) ->(Value, Value), (Int, Int) -> (Value, Value), ...)` and then `val data = List((Int, Int), (Int, Int), ...).toDS[(Int, Int)]` and finally `val result = data.flatMap(lookUp.get)`

Comment: I think this might be a bit slow due to the size of my dataset.

Comment: Which one? If the `data` one or the `lookUp` one?

Comment: The data is about 400 million rows, and the look up is about 12k rows, I think the 400 mil is the problem ?

Comment: I believe `lookUp` should be small enough so you can have it as a normal Scala **Map**. `data` shouldn't be a problem because you will have a **Dataset** not a **List**, so it will be distributed. Now the question is how you would create that dataset, but that is another question.